# Jackson unwrapping of null value objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-data-rest

Let's say I have `Description` value object:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class Description {
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private final String description;
}
```

and `Product` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Product extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private final Description description;   
}
```

I created custom serializer for `Description`:

```
static class DescriptionSerializer extends StdSerializer<Description> {
    DescriptionSerializer() {
        super(Description.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Description value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (value != null) {
            jgen.writeString(value.getDescription());
        } else {
            jgen.writeNull();
        }
    }
}
```

When I create:

```
Product product = new Product(new Description("description"));
```

and serialize it:

```
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(spec);
```

it returns JSON: `{"description":"description"}`

When I create:

```
Product product = new Product(null);
```

it returns `{}`,

but I would expect `{"description":null}`

If I remove `@JsonUnwrapped`, it works as I'd expect, but for non-null `Description`, it would create nested object

Is there a way to keep unwrapping for fields with null value objects in a similar way how it is done for built-in Java types?

Answer (score 0):

To have what you want you should try with:

```
Product p = new Product(new Description(null));
```

In the json

```
{"description":"description"}
```

the `Description`, as a container of other fields exists, what is null is the value of the `description` field inside the `Description` object.

The two kind of serializations have different meaning.

To easily manage it in your code you can have a class like:

```
public class Product {
    private Description description;

    public Product(Description d) {
        this.description = d;
    }

    public Product() {
        this(new Description()); //all fields are null
    }

    public Product(String description) {
         return new Product(new Description(description));
    }
}
```

The last two constructor I would prefer as a factory methods, but it is just matter of code style.

Comment: The problem in my case is that JPA/Hibernate/Spring Data populates Description value object as null, not as Description(null).. Even if I tried using JPA attribute converter

Comment: I see, the problem here is that things gets messy when you try to use the same object for multiple representations. I think you are using the `Product` class as data model to store in your database, and as response of a rest api. In this case I would return the data structure as it is stored, or having different objects for storage and api responses, depending on how the service is used. Different objects can smell of code duplication, but with that duplication it's easier to evolve them in different ways.

Comment: Yeah.. that's the thing.. however using the same domain model for persistence and jackson (de)serialization is one of the key design considerations in Spring Data REST project which I use. It just seems this is something I'll have to be pragmatic about and adapt frontend client accordingly.
In the meantime, I posted question https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1175 and https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1887

Comment: Yes Spring Data REST helps you if you use the same representation to store and read from the rest api the data, so why you want them different (hiding the `Description` object from the json)?
Depending on how much your model is different it can be a pain manage the different visualization fighting with jackson/jpa/hibernate/spring annotations. I found better to have more code but easier to change.
For what I understand it seems that if you manage the code calling the rest apis it would be simpler to have the `Description` object also in the json.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to hide `Description` object. What I want to achieve is when `Description` object is populated, then unwrap it. If it is null, then put "description": null in JSON result instead of not putting anything. Initially I was not using value objects, I just used String description in `Product` entity and stringly typed description was rendered as `"description": null`. The goal is to keep backward compatibility with react fronted client

Comment: In terms of architecture.. it all depends on how your domain model is modeled.. whether DDD is properly applied, especially aggregates. If it is properly modeled, you should not need additional mapping layer between persistence and REST representations, afaik.

Comment: more or less you're right, but depending on who calls the domain service. If you're exposing that data to a frontend you shouldn't give them the domain model, because otherwise the page needs to change everytime your domain model change. In your case for me it seems better to have DTOs that explicitate the legacy (react) data structure, and have the rest api querying your domain model and then transform these objects in the legacy ones. In this way you're free to change the structure of your aggregates without the need to change the FE (react) code.

Comment: In DDD you have different layers, and the "view" of the MVC is something related to the action the user need to perform, so is something "user oriented" this is the reason because it should be separated from the model of your domain (what you store). In this way they can evolve separately (maybe in one view you want to show the name and price of a product and the average price of the other products of the same kind, in this way the view is totally different from your domain model.